# Trouble rejecting a specific character in my RegEx

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I'm running the following regular expression to check a username:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])\w{2,25}\s*$
```

It works fine but now I need to amend it to reject any instances of underscores(_). I've tried wedging ^(?!_)$ in there but it doesn't seem to work for me in that it either checks at the beginning or the end.

I know a little about regular expressions but I'm hazy on all the classes. I've found a great resource for it at http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Thanks for the help, folks.

Comment: What is the language here? `\w` can match Unicode characters in some languages - do you want to keep the class of characters that also contains `_`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This should work for you:**

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.\-]{2,25}\s*$
```

**What this regex will validate:**

- The first character is a letter
- The input contains only alphanumeric characters (i added `-` also)
         *if dont want `-` just remove `\-`*
- The input is `2-25` characters long

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could always remove the `\w` by its character class excluding `_`.

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]{2,25}\s*$
```

Comment: @sjbennett Did you also need periods (`.`) in the usernames you required?

Comment: they are no longer accepted in the form so everything should be golden here!

Comment: @sjbennett Huh... the answer you accepted accepts periods as well.